# Why can't I register my credit card on the Marketplace?

Tags: store

I am "lucky" that Croatia is one of the "new" countries which have their marketplace up and running. I can live with the fact that some apps aren't available here (but it's confusing that the guys from Bookviser told me a month ago they checked the app to be published worldwide) but the thing that's really anoying me now is that I can not register my credit card.

I have tried two cards and both have been rejected for some strange reason. All fields are marked red so I have to reenter them again. Microsoft seems to be the only company which has problems with my credit card(s) (Paypal/Ebay, Amazon, some poker sites, MoneyBookers and some smaller web shops all accept them).

I have emailed Microsoft about this but the only response I have received is that I should check my region, if I have entered all data correctly etc. But everything is fine. I don't get it.

Did anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where did you try to register your card, through the phone or through the web? I have had clients who had the same problem, but it was through the phone.

The solution was to go to billing.microsoft.com. Here is a snippet from the credit card page...

> About payment method status When you view or add a payment method,
>   Microsoft Online Services immediately verifies whether or not the
>   payment method is valid, and then displays the status of the payment
>   method information.
>
> The status will be one of the following:
>
> - Good:  The payment method information is valid and current.
> - Declined: The payment method was declined for one of several reasons,
>     such as insufficient funds or an expired credit card. To correct the
>     problem, use one of the following steps:
>
>   > Follow the instructions in How do I use a new payment method to set up
>   >     a new payment method.  Contact your bank or credit card company to
>   >     make sure that the payment method is valid.  Contact Customer Support.
> - Expiration pending: Because the credit card will expire soon, you must
>     update the credit card information with the new expiration date. To
>     update the expiration date, follow these steps:
>
>   > On the Payment method information page, click Edit payment method
>   >     information.  Select the new expiration date for your credit card, and
>   >     then click Save.
> - Expired: The credit card has expired and you must update the credit
>     card information with the new expiration date. To update the
>     expiration date, follow these steps:
>
>   > On the Payment method information page, click Edit payment method
>   >     information.  Select the new expiration date for the credit card, and
>   >     then click Save.
> - Removed:  The payment method has been removed from your account and the
>     payment method is listed for historical purposes.

You can fix your credit card issue by going to the link below (you'll need to sign in)
https://billing.microsoft.com/home.aspx

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Sign in to the Billing and Account Management website.
2. Under Payment method activity, click Go to payment method information.
3. Under Payment method information for this account, click Use a different payment method.
4. Click Add new credit card, and then click Next. (or) Click Add new Direct Debit, and then click Next.
5. On the Confirm transfer page, confirm the balances and services you want to transfer, and then click Next.
6. Enter the information for the new payment method, and then click Save.

Comment: Thanks for this... I am searching for a place to "Add something new" but the only thing I see in the Payment method activity is "Advance payment" which I never used and Microsoft points. Think I have to live with this till MS sorts things out.

Comment: After going to Payment Method Activity, go to "use different payment method". That is where you can add a new method.

Comment: For some reason I can't see this options... http://imgur.com/aMJSt

Comment: Here's the link to get direct support for your problem. Pick the service you want and send them an email. This way you can have a real person make the change for you. https://billing.microsoft.com/helppane.aspx?helppagename=BILLING_CONC_ContactCustomerSupport

Comment: "Pre-paid cards, debit cards, and gift cards (even those with a Visa or MasterCard logo) do not qualify as international cards and are not currently accepted by Marketplace." Totaly forgot that I have only debit cards... and the credit card I have hasnt got a CCV number... Have to ask my bank for help then... Strange that only MS has problems with my cards

Comment: To add to this, now that Windows Phone 8 has the Wallet, you can add a credit card, prepaid card, gift card, etc. in there and use it for app purchases.